# Adding a python script to the PATH environment variable when installing with pip

Tags: python, django

When installing django via pip, the PATH environment variable is modified to let the user access django-admin directly in the terminal. (django-admin startproject project_name)

I would like to the same for my pip package.
I looked at how modifying environment variable using python but  **os.environ["PATH"]** wont get saved once the python script is ended.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add modules that you installed with pip to PATH?

Comment: @sP_ when entering "pip install foo" I would like to add at the same time foo-script.py to be accessible via the terminal by simply entering "foo-script"

Comment: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point

Comment: This is probably a dup; if not, I can write an answer. But either way, the answer is just going to quote from and link to that page.

Comment: try this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458250/6680829

Comment: @AsifMohammed No, that's a completely different thing.

Comment: isn't that making python program globally accessible ?? @abarnert

Comment: sorry. i have misunderstood @abarnert

Comment: @AsifMohammed That's about creating a standalone executable that doesn't require a Python installation, which the OP hasn't asked for. And, after doing that, the OP would still need to create an installer to install that executable and get it onto the user's PATH, just as they already need to do for their Python script—except that now they'd have to build an installer/rpm/etc. for each platform instead of just relying on `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is to give `setuptools` an [Entry Point](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point).

Instead of writing a script, you write a function in one of your modules.

For example, add this line to your `setup` call in `setup.py`:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['mytool'=mypkg.myscript:myfunc'],
}
```

… and `setuptools` will, at install time, automatically create a script named `mytool` that imports mypkg.myscript`and calls its`myfunc`, all in a way that's appropriate for whatever Python installation the user used to`pip install`your package, and put`mytool`onto the user's`PATH`.

This way, it takes care of all kinds of portability issues you never even thought of. What if the user is on Windows and their default Python is 2.7 but they used `py -3 -m pip` to install it? They'll get a file named `mytool.py` instead of `mytool`, and it'll have a Windows `py`-launcher-compatible shbang line, and it'll just work.

---

Occasionally, you can't reorganize things that way, and you have to manually write a script. In that case, just give `setuptools` the path to the script, by adding this argument to your `setup` call:

```
scripts=['bin/mytool']
```

`setuptools` can't do all of its magic here, but it can still get the script installed into the user's `PATH`.

---

Of course all of this depends on Python being set up properly. But however Python managed to put `pip` and `django-admin` on your `PATH`, then it will put your script on the `PATH` in the exact same way.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much